Use 'fold' to wrap lines at 72 column
Test file:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

If using
script.sh input.txt output.txt

sed 's/ - /--/g
     s/ \{0,1\}[—–] \{0,1\}/--/g
     s/…/.../g
     s/\\\*/†/g
     s/*/\//g
     s/\\\././g' $1 |
fold -sw 72 |
sed 's/ *$//g' > $2

the output is
------------------------------------------------------------------------ <- 72 characters
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim
veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

But why not this?
------------------------------------------------------------------------ <- 72 characters
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim veniam
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
id est laborum.

That is, why the word veniam was moved from the 2nd line to the 3rd? Isn't there enough space for it?
man fold:

-s: Fold line after the last blank character within the first width column positions (or bytes).

I use fold supplied with macOS, but if using GNU fold, the output file is the same.

Related awk script posted at script-to-format-markdown-as-plain-text.

Because fold just folds. It doesn't know anything about words, really, it just has that nice option to break on spaces. However, if you look at the output closely, you will see that while it does break on spaces, it still keeps them there in the output. You can see them by converting all spaces at the end of a line to another character, like _:
$ fold -w72 -s file | sed 's/ $/_/'
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo_
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim_
veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea_
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate_
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint_
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt_
mollit anim id est laborum.

See those _ at the end of every line? Those are the spaces. This means that when handling this line:
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim_

We have this many characters:
$ echo 'tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim_' | fold -w1 | cat -n | tail
    57  n
    58  i
    59  m
    60   
    61  m
    62  i
    63  n
    64  i
    65  m
    66  _

By the time we get to minim , we are at position 66. If we also add veniam  (note the space after veniam, the only place the tool is allowed to cut), that takes us over the line:
$ echo 'tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim veniam ' | fold -w1 | cat -n | tail
    64  i
    65  m
    66   
    67  v
    68  e
    69  n
    70  i
    71  a
    72  m
    73   

So the space after veniam is the 73rd character, and fold can only break on a space that is at a maximum of position 72. That's why it isn't including veniam.
If you allow it to break anywhere, it can do it:
$ echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim veniam quis' | fold -w 72
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo t
empor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim veniam 
quis


Thanks. This was so trivial, but I would probably lost several hours trying to figure out what is going on. So it seems the simplest solution is to change 72 to 73. Edit: Oops, no, this would lead that some words will exceed the 72 column. Ok, then I just leave the script as is.

@jsx97 well, there are a lot of things in your script that could be simplified or don't make much sense. Why so many \\\ , why so many sed calls, and why [[:space:]] instead of just   (do you really expect tabs or carriage returns etc?). If you want to, there are various improvements that could be made, but you would need to post a question explaining what the logic of your script actually is. You could try sed ... | fold -sw 73  | sed 's/ $//' | fold -sw 72, so folding to 73 characters, then removing any trailing spaces and folding again to 72. That gets minim veniam on 1 line.

Asking how to refine the code that already works would be more suitable for Code Review Stack Exchange, if I understand correctly. I have updated it according to your recommendations, and edited it in the body of question accordingly. Let me know if you something "smelly" there. Addentum: "Why so many backslashes?" - To match \* (and then to replace it with †), \\* is not enough, and it is required to use \\\*.

@EdMorton, s/*/ is defined with BRE (so as long as you don't use sed's -E/-P... options), the OP had [—–], not [--], they are two different kinds of dash characters.

@EdMorton, ssed (which at some point could be seen as the development version of GNU sed) has had perl-like regexp support for decades though with -R (and -r for ERE like in GNU sed), ast-open's sed has -P for perl-like regexps (not via PCRE) and some other regexp flavours. I don't know whether there's any plan to add perl-like support in GNU sed. I've got the feeling they added -P to GNU grep rather reluctantly (it's still optional and still flagged as somewhat experimental)

If you want your second result, instead of using fold, use fmt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim minim veniam
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim
id est laborum.

This seems to match your expected output exactly, and with default options.

fmt -s would be closer to the OP's fold-based approach. Beware that fmt (GNU fmt at least) contrary to fold won't break words that are longer than 72 characters, so you could end up with lines longer than 72 characters/cells. GNU fmt also doesn't support multibyte characters (let alone double-width or zero-width ones) and counts bytes only.
